# Not able to lookup IPv6 in GEOIP database of maxmind

Tags: logstash, geoip, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, maxmind

```
geoip {
source => "remoteip"
target => "geoip"
database => "/etc/logstash/mmcity6.dat"
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
}
date {
locale => "en"
match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss +0530" ]
target => "@timestamp"
}
kv {
field_split => "&?"
}
}
```

FORWARDEDipV6 [CLIENTIPV6] HOSTNAME [25/Mar/2016:19:47:13 +0530] HIT "GET URL HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" 0.000 -

```
"forwarded_ip": "ipv6",
"remoteip": "IPV6",
"loghost": "HOSTN,E",
"timestamp": "25/Mar/2016:19:47:13 +0530",
"cache": "HIT",
"httpmethod": "GET",
"request": "URL",
"httpversion": "1.1",
"response": "200",
"bytes": 5,
"agent": "\"Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)\"",
"request_time": 0
```

BUT I AM NOT GETTING GEO LOCATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Support has just come in Elastic STack 5 ..